# HashMap and classes

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to use a HashMap to store some classes.
here is a view of my simplified code.

```
HashMap<Integer, MyClass> map = new HashMap<Integer, MyClass>
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
for (int i = 0; i<MAX;i++){
    myClass.counter=i;
    map.put(i, myClass);
    myClass.modifySomeInternalParameters(i);
    myClass.anotherCounter+(i*2);
}
```

Whenever I reach the last statement, anotherCounter gets updated for ALL the entries in the Map. (same for counter actually)
I have tried changing the put statement to

```
map.put(i, new MyClass (myClass));
```

to no avail.
I have the feeling that the HashMap does not create a copy of myClass to store it, but rather looks at its content in memory. Is there a way to prevent this if I don't want to recreate myClass and repopulate it each time.
Using 'Clone' in my loop sounds ugly.

TIA

Comment: Why are you not using a List?

Comment: He will have the same issue with a List (but that's a good point)

Comment: Your first assumption is correct.  The `HashMap` is using the reference of the object you created, because you've told it not to do it any other way.  Saying *"Using 'Clone' in my loop sounds ugly"* is like saying "I don't want to use pointers in C", pointless, `Clone` is exactly what you want, this is what it was created for.  Your only other solution is to, as you stated to use `new MyClass(myClass)` using `myClass` as template and populating the new reference with it.  The bigger problem from there is then knowing how to determine the difference between them ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer in those cases, I would prefer to use another class that handles the dirty job of cloning/creating the new instance instead of using a constructor that receives the same argument. IMO you should separate the data holders from the business logic and utility classes.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i agree, in that case, he should use a Factory that can be used to "clone" a template object

Answer (score 2):

You're putting the same object into the map over and over - move the MyClass declaration inside the loop.

Comment: My problem is that modifySomeInternalParameters() does some modifications to my class internals, I can't just reconstruct my class from scratch at each iteration. Well I am sure I can, but I'm gonna to make local copies of my internal parameters. I was expecting a more elegant solution.

Comment: @user1654757 there is an elegant solution: [Factory Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: Thanks Luigi, I do know which exact class needs creating, re-creating it just makes my objects lose their state. I was also after a 'simple' solution

Comment: What does `modifySomeInternalParameters()` do? I suspect there may be a better way.

Otherwise, you're basically asking how to clone without using `.clone()`.

Comment: There is no magic in Java for copying objects so you can modify them later on.  Why do you expect `HashMap` to have that magic?  You'll have to do this yourself.

Comment: I am not expecting Magic, I merely expect map.put(i, new MyClass (myClass)); to put in my map an instance of MyClass different to myClass

Comment: @user1654757: That will, of course, create a new instance of MyClass, but you haven't shown what that constructor does - why is it not doing what you expect?

Comment: This is my copy constructor 
 public MyClass(MyClass aClass){
  super();
  counter=aClass.counter;
  anotherCounter=aClass.anotherCounter;
  memberDate=aClass.memberData;
 }
I have used local variables to store the values of the data members and repopulate my object after creation, and the content of the map get changed for all entries when i modify the local variable.

Comment: It looks like the local variables do not get copied to the myClass member variables inside the map IF they are primitives (with my code an int). I have a Calendar and a int[] that do get copied. (and yes, both of these get new'ed in the myClass Constructor and copy constructor)

Comment: Can you post the code for MyClass? Or at least the copy constructor and the field declarations.  It will be a lot easier than trying to guess.

Comment: Right, the problems was that my copy contructor was using assignments for the member data rather than clone(). <<memberDate=aClass.memberData; >>memberData = aClass.memberData.clone();